# run two programs on start up raspberry pi

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi

I am writing a shell script so when my raspberry pi is turned on it automatically runs a shell script that starts two programs running one in the background and the other not.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd rpi2ardu/
sudo ./Main
```

Then I want that first program to run in background done by the shell script - how do I do this?

The next program:

```
java -cp ".:someLib:someLib" myprog
```

These will all be incorporated into the same shell script but as you can probably notice this isn't working. I am new to raspberry pi and linux so any help would be great thanks.

Comment: What OS is the Raspberry Pi running?

Answer (score 0):

Log in as root

First you make a file in /etc/init.d called mystartup.sh

You need to make it executable via chmod +x /etc/init.d/mystartup.sh

Set it up to run at boot with update-rc.d mystartup.sh defaults 100

edit mystartup.sh and append /path/to/file.sh and save

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `&` at the end of the first command:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd rpi2ardu/
sudo ./Main &
java -cp ".:someLib:someLib" myprog
```

be careful, `java` will be executed regardless of the `Main` status, this is not safe if the second program is dependent from the first one